# C thread handling with two processor groups

Tags: c, multithreading, numa

I have a new PC with an AMD Threadripper 3990x, which has 64 cores and 128 threads.

Now Windows 10 can only handle 64 cores in one processor group. So now Windows makes two processor groups.

I have written software that creates N processes. I check as follows how many processes are present:

```
SYSTEM_INFO sysi;
GetSystemInfo(&sysi);
klas->thread_maxcore = min(sysi.dwNumberOfProcessors, MAX_THREADS);
klas->thread_max = klas->thread_maxcore;
```

How do I have to adjust my code to use all 128 threads? With my current code I can only run 64 processes at a time, so only one processor group can be used.

Comment: What specific version/type of `Windows 10` to you have?  They each behave differently with your processor. (as pointed out in the link posted below.)

Comment: I use w10 professional

Comment: Consider using some recent [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution). Their NUMA support might be better on your new PC. And code in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) or [C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) which has better and platform neutral multithreading

Answer (score 2):

*How do I have to adjust my code to use all 128 threads*

The short answer is to either make your software *processor group aware*, or force your configuration to have only one processor group.

As you have noted, Windows default, when seeing more than 64 threads is to separate them into processor groups.  This might be why you are seeing what appears to be a smaller thread count.  While the thread count is less than what you are expecting, it is possibly representing only part of the total system thread count.

There is a setting for *simultaneous multi-threading*, and this by default, in Windows 10, is turned on.   With your 64 core processor, when *simultaneous multi-threading* is enabled, the system will show 128 threads, but these are split into two groups.  This default Windows behavior may be what is preventing you from seeing (having visibility) all of your threads.  Regarding your specific request *How do I have to adjust my code to use all 128 threads*,

> ...When the program is running inside the group, unless it is processor
>   group aware, then it can only access other threads in the same group...

So, the answer is to either make you software processor group aware, or make your settings to place all cores into a single processor group by disabling *simultaneous multi-threading*,  thus allowing your software to spawn all 128 threads.
Methods, and trade-offs for both options are presented in greater detail in the links below...

Read the details here...
[The 64 core Threadripper 3990x CPU Review](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15483/amd-threadripper-3990x-review/3).

Some links that may assist in making your software processor group aware:

- [C++11 threads, affinity, and
  hyper-threading](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/)
- [Thread pools and Windows processor groups](https://chrisgreendevelopmentblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/thread-pools-and-windows-processor-groups/)

Excerpt *adapted* `C++` code from previous link (As this question is tagged `C`, consider this as *pseudo code*)

```
void DistributeThreads(void)
{
#if OS_WINDOWS_64
    //!!BUG!! need to skip this code for old windows versions
        int nNumGroups = GetActiveProcessorGroupCount();
    if ( nNumGroups > 1 )
    {
        Log( "System has %d processor groups", nNumGroups );
        for(int i = 0; i < nNumGroups; i++ )
        {
            Log(" group %d has %d processors", i, ( int ) GetMaximumProcessorCount( i ) );
        }
        int nCurGroup = 0;
        int nNumRemaining = GetMaximumProcessorCount( nCurGroup );
        for( int i = 0; i < m_threads.size(); i ++ )
        {
            auto hndl = m_threads[i].native_handle();
            GROUP_AFFINITY oldaffinity;
            if ( GetThreadGroupAffinity( hndl, &oldaffinity ) )
            {
                //Log( "thread %d, old msk = %x, old grp = %llx", i, oldaffinity.Mask, oldaffinity.Group );
                GROUP_AFFINITY affinity;
                affinity = oldaffinity;
                if ( affinity.Group != nCurGroup )
                {
                    affinity.Group = nCurGroup;
                    auto bSucc = SetThreadGroupAffinity( hndl, &affinity, nullptr );
                    if ( ! bSucc )
                    {
                        Log( "failed to set gr aff err=%x", (int) GetLastError() );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log( "Set group for thread %d to %d", i, nCurGroup );
                    }
                    --nNumRemaining;
                    if ( nNumRemaining == 0 )
                    {
                        nCurGroup = min( nCurGroup + 1 , nNumGroups - 1 );
                        nNumRemaining = GetMaximumProcessorCount( nCurGroup );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Note:  Search MSDN for function definitions, eg like this one: [GetMaximumProcessorCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getmaximumprocessorcount)

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I have edited, and believe the content is now more relevant to OP question.  Thanks.

Comment: never worked with processor groups in c ... may you can make me an simple example?

Comment: @Felix - have you looked at the example code in the links?  They both go into sufficient detail on explanation, and provide code to illustrate. :)  (See edit in answer.)

Answer (score 0):

That link is to my code and article.
I just bought a 128 core/256 thread and system and as you'd expect, windows processor groups mean most programs only use 1/4 of my cores.
Including the visual c++ parallel STL algorithms :(.
That code works, but save yourself all the headaches and just use Intel TBB.
It really sucks when you download a threaded application for windows and notice it only uses 25% of your system.
Don't expect msoft to do anything about it. I contacted the visual c++ team and all they care about us making excuses for the issue.